# Number of pending edits unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Observe:

[image]

Firefox 3.6.13 under Ubuntu Lucid, if that matters.

Comment: Yup, same in Chrome on Mac OS X.

Comment: With Safari on Mac OS X, it's dark grey text on orange background, so it's readable, but not very clear.