# The number showing the number of suggested edits still pending is not visible

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The number that is showing the pending edits to review is visible on top of the page, but it is not visible in the review page.

[image: screenshot]

Looking closely, the number is shown, but the color is too similar to the background one.

The screenshot was taken after approving an edit, the following one shows what I see before approving a pending edit.

[image: screenshot]

This is similar to [Number of pending edits unreadable](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/627/number-of-pending-edits-unreadable), but that report has been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), and closed as too localized, while I am facing the issue again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for this will be pushed out in the next build.

Comment: Purfect! Thank you!